Why is statResult empty after being filled by useEffect in react typescript?
statResult is empty outside of useeffect, even after setting the isLoading to false which only is set to false once the statresult is filled with the data.

import { StatPanelProps } from "./StatPanelprops";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"


export function StatPanel(Props: StatPanelProps) {

    const [statResult, setStatResult] = useState<any>("")
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        async function load() {
            var statResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/stats/${Props.name}`)
            var statResultJson = await statResponse.json();
            setStatResult(statResultJson)
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
        load()
    }, [])
    if (isLoading) {
        return <div>"Loading..."</div>
    }

    if (!isLoading) {
        return (<ul>
            <li id={(Props.id + 1).toString()}>Név: {statResult.name} </li>
            <li id={(Props.id + 2).toString()}>Nyert: {statResult.win}</li>
            <li id={(Props.id + 3).toString()}>Vesztett: {statResult.loss}</li>
            <li id={(Props.id + 4).toString()}>Arány: {(statResult.win / (statResult.win + statResult.loss)) * 100}</li>
        </ul>)
    }
}

I tried to log the statresult everywhere. It only has value inside the useeffect function.

Check this question

You should add Props.name in dependency array of useEffect to run useEffect whenever the Props.name value is changed. Without any value in dependency array your useEffect will be run only on component initialization (in the past when react component was created with class this method was named onComponentDidMount - link to legacy docs https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
You should do it like this to run your useEffect whenever props are changed
  useEffect(() => {
        async function load() {
            var statResponse = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/stats/${Props.name}`)
            var statResultJson = await statResponse.json();
            setStatResult(statResultJson)
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
        load()
    }, [Props.name])

